# Text area not rendering React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure why my text area isn't rendering if someone could suggest what I'm missing or what I've done wrong I'd be forever grateful.

I'm not sure whether maybe I should try rending it in the App.js file.

I'm also sure I don't need to import the App.js file to the CardCheck.js because it's a child.

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import CardCheck from "./CardCheck";

class App extends React.Component() {
  state = {
    cardNumber: "",
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ cardNumber: event.target.value });
  };

  handleClick = () => {
    const { cardNumber } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      cardNumber: "",
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { cardNumber } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Taken Yo Money</h1>
        <CardCheck
          cardNumber={cardNumber}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
          handleClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;


function CardCheck(props) {
  const { cardNumber, handleChange, handleClick } = props;

  return (
    <div className="TweetInput">
      <div className="bar-wrapper"></div>
      <textarea onChange={handleChange} value={cardNumber}></textarea>
      <footer>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Enter Card Details</button>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
export default CardCheck;
```

Comment: class App extends React.Component, Component is not a function.

Comment: Why would that effect it? The example I'm working off converted the function App to a class also.

Comment: Its just not a function, hence you should not do Component()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from `class App extends React.Component()`. It should be

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    //rest of the code
}
``
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `class App extends React.Component()` with `class App extends Component {` 
The `Component` is imported from `import React, { Component } from "react";`

It should fix the rendering issue